# jQuery .live function problem

Tags: jquery

I have an element that gets an attribute added to it by jquery when the page loads. The attribute is called jcarouselindex. I need to get the value of this attribute when the document loads.

Ive got the selector and if it wasn't added dynamically could just do:

```
id = jQuery('#gallery-carousel li.selected').attr("jcarouselindex");
```

But since its been added dynamically the value of id is undefined. I think I need to use .live() does anyone know how I would get the value of this attribute please?

Comment: Actually it should work. `live` is only useful to bind events to elements that do not **exist** at the time of binding. You should be able to read attributes that you added to objects in the usual way. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: If this is loaded when the page loads, can you just run the getValue code after the statement that loads adds the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code above should work. .live() is used for a different purpose. I think you may be trying to access the attr before it is being dynamically added. Try calling this function using a setTimeout, which will ensure all the existing code gets executed.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    id = jQuery('#gallery-carousel li.selected').attr("jcarouselindex");
}, 0);
```

I'm assuming your code is already within a $(function(){}); block.

Answer (score 0):

Live should be used to bind event handlers to elements which do not exists on the page at the time of binding.

I think you need to look at the execution timings that you have on the page. Your selector includes the class 'selected' on the li so I assume an event must trigger the addition of the selected class. does this event occur after the jcarouselindex attribute values have been added? if so then you should capture this value when the selection event occurs.

Unfortunately you have not given us much detail to go on so more info could help us to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

`live` is not for that, but for event handlers.  You have to run that code after the attribute has been set, so, try with:

```
$.ready(function(){
  id = jQuery('#gallery-carousel li.selected').attr("jcarouselindex");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are using the jcarousel plugin?

If so there is a callback you can use on the initialisation of the carousel:

```
$('#gallery-carousel').jcarousel({
    initCallback: function () {
        var id = $('#gallery-carousel li.selected').attr("jcarouselindex");
        // do something with id
    }
});
```

This way you can be sure that the carousel has initialised before executing your code.

see: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ for further details.